# Plugin for Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result not working

Tags: magento2, plugin, di

I am trying to disable the default sorting based on price, that is happening on shipping methods.

I found that this is happening in `sortRatesByPrice()`

> vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Rate/Result.php

```
public function sortRatesByPrice()
{
    if (!is_array($this->_rates) || !count($this->_rates)) {
        return $this;
    }
    /* @var $rate \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method */
    foreach ($this->_rates as $i => $rate) {
        $tmp[$i] = $rate->getPrice();
    }

    natsort($tmp);

    foreach ($tmp as $i => $price) {
        $result[] = $this->_rates[$i];
    }

    $this->reset();
    $this->_rates = $result;
    return $this;
}
```

I basically just want to disable the sorting that happens here. (I.e. comment `natsort($tmp)`)

I have tried to create a plugin for this, but this is not working.

This is my `di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result">
        <plugin name="dm_shipping_sortshipping" type="DM\Shipping\Plugin\Rate\Result" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
    
</config>
```

This is my plugin

```
<?php

    namespace DM\Shipping\Plugin\Rate;

    class Result {

        public function beforeSortRatesByPrice()
        {
            $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/dm_debug.log');
            $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('beforeSortRatesByPrice');
        }

        public function aroundSortRatesByPrice()
        {
            $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/dm_debug.log');
            $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('aroundSortRatesByPrice');
        }

        public function afterSortRatesByPrice()
        {
            $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/dm_debug.log');
            $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('beforeSortRatesByPrice');
        }

    }
```

Why are none of these firing? Log is empty.

Comment: DId you ever get a working solution? As I'm having the same issues

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an around plugin, you don't need the before and after plugins.
As you can see in the magento dev docs (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html), you are missing the methods arguments. Every plugin method must have at least the subject:

```
        public function beforeSortRatesByPrice(\Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $subject)
        {
            $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/dm_debug.log');
            $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('beforeSortRatesByPrice');
        }

        public function aroundSortRatesByPrice(\Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $subject, callable $proceed)
        {
            $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/dm_debug.log');
            $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('aroundSortRatesByPrice');
        }

        public function afterSortRatesByPrice(\Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $subject, $result)
        {
            $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/dm_debug.log');
            $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('beforeSortRatesByPrice');
        }
```

Remember to clean generated code (rm -rf generated/*)

Comment: Still not working with your suggested fixes :(

Comment: Can you check your exception log pls?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin for `Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result` didn't work for me, because this sorting is called in `Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\CarrierResult::getAllRates()` which calls with `parent::sortRatesByPrice();` and i guess this way doesn't "use" the plugin preference.

So, instead i made a plugin for Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\CarrierResult

```
<type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\CarrierResult">
    <plugin name="custom_shipping_sortshipping" type="Vendor\Shipping\Plugin\Rate\CarrierResult" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
</type>
```

Then in the `Vendor\Shipping\Plugin\Rate\CarrierResult` you can use the plugin features to create a before/around/after as needed. In my case i used the afterGetAllRates, for ex:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Shipping\Plugin\Rate;

class CarrierResult
{

    public function afterGetAllRates(\Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\CarrierResult $subject, $result)
    {
        // Custom sort function on $result

        return $result;
    }

}
```

Maybe it's a bit late, but found this question when searching for a solution. And since i found one, it might help someone else.